# UIImage at end of UITextView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uitextfield

I have an UITextField, at the end of the textfield I want to add an UIImage.

When I put an UIImageView on top of the UITextField, the UIImageView is always (duh!) visible in top of the UITextField.

What code do I need to write so that at the end of the text from the UITextField the UIImageView appears?

Comment: What exactly you want to do ?. Put some code so we can understand properly.And UIImage is not a controller , it is set in UIImageView

Comment: not understand what you try to do. Please put some code or elaborate it more

Comment: Could you show an example, do you mean `NSTextAttachment` with `NSAttributedString`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No code needed, just add the proper constraints on the interface builder. Command-click to the image and bind it to the text field, then select horizontal (or vertical) spacing from the popup list.

Answer (score 1):

You may prefer to use a UIButton and adjust the Title and Image edge insets in the Attributes inspector.

Set the image in the "Image" field, add your text then...

Your values will be different but these are the fields to change:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can uncheck "User Interaction Enabled" if you don't need to handle a tap.